# Java comparator for array of strings not working

Tags: comparator

I have copied in my code so you can see what i am trying to do. The first part works fine before I try to sort it, I just want it to output the cities from long length to short length as the first part outputs fine and I am so stuck, would really appreciate some help.

```
public class Q3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String strCity[] = new String[3]; //declaring array of three Irish Cities
     //adding elements to the array
     strCity[0] ="Cork";

     strCity[1] ="Dublin";

     strCity[2] ="Waterford";

     //declaring the shortest to longest in the array before sorting
     System.out.println("This is the list before sorting:");
     for (int i=0;i<strCity.length;i++){

              System.out.println(strCity[i]);

     }
}
}

class comp implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2)
  {
  System.out.println("This is the sorted list:");
      if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". What's the problem? Where is your attempt at sorting the array?

Comment: sorry, what is not actually happening is there is nothing outputting for the second line I want, which is where the comparator comes in, I want it to output by length of the strings I declared. I am hoping for "Waterford, Dublin, Cork", The first output is fine starting with Cork it's what I want. Sorry if I am confusing. @peter

Comment: I don't see anything that actually uses the comparator here.

Answer (score 0):

Do like

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strCity[] = new String[3]; //declaring array of three Irish Cities
        //adding elements to the array
        strCity[0] = "Cork";

        strCity[1] = "Dublin";

        strCity[2] = "W ";

        //declaring the shortest to longest in the array before sorting
        System.out.println("This is the list before sorting:");
        for (int i = 0; i < strCity.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(strCity[i]);

        }
        Arrays.sort(strCity, new LengthComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strCity));
    }

    static class LengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Remove print method from Comparator. compare method calls for each comparisons performed by sorting algorithm.

Comment: Ok I deleted the comparator line I put in and tried this it has come up with errors and not out putting anything for me. I have tried everything today and nothing is working for me!

Comment: I created a comparator class and a strCity class, perhaps that is where I went wrong?

Comment: if you haven't noticed your comp() class is mentioned as LengthComparator in my code so first line in my code is Arrays.sort(strCity,new comp()); in your case

Comment: i created the new LengthComparator class now, still errors will keep at it.